# PostgreSQL IN operator does not work but pattern matching does

Tags: sql, postgresql

as the title says, please find the block of codes that worked and didn't work respectively.

```
select *
from public.transactions
where id in ('ABCDE-3131243553O2')
```

The query above didn't work but the one below did.

```
select *
from public.transactions
where id ~* 'ABCDE-3131243553O2'
```

Does anyone know any particular reason why? I have been googling but to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us your sample data please

Comment: `~*` is case-insensitive, `in` is case-sensitive. --- FYI: `in` with a single value is the same as `=`. --- For a case-sensitive regex match, use `~` without the `*`.

Comment: Likely it's probably case-sensitivity?  ~* is a case-insensitive pattern match, where as I suspect IN will probably be an inherent case-sensitive match.

Comment: I see. How do you suggest I go about if I were to have multiple IDs?

Comment: Please add some example

Comment: Also, the regular expression is not anchored.

Comment: The regex matches _anywhere_. So that will e.g. also return rows with `'xxxxABCDE-3131243553O2xxxx'` in the `id` column

Answer (score 0):

These are not equivalent at all.  Consider:

```
where id ~* 'ABCDE-3131243553O2'
```

This matches *any* string that contains the expression.  For instance this returns *both* rows.

```
select *
from (values ('ABCDE-3131243553O2'), ('blahblahblahABCDE-3131243553O2foofoofoo')) v(id)
where  id ~* 'ABCDE-3131243553O2';
```

The equivalent regular expression for `=` or `in` is:

```
where id ~* '^ABCDE-3131243553O2$'
```

This anchors the pattern, so no other characters are allowed.

If you are not getting a match using `in` when you are expecting one, then a likely cause are hidden characters in the data (or perhaps the comparison value).  The most common "hidden" characters are spaces at the beginning or end.  Another issue could be look-alike characters.  Is the `1` really a `1` or a lower case `L`?